# Is it possible to create a regular sql server table using a table type?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Using 2008 R2, I have created a User-Defined Table Type as below.

```
IF TYPE_ID('ttypRPStats') IS NOT NULL  
   DROP TYPE dbo.ttypRPStats  

CREATE TYPE dbo.ttypRPStats AS TABLE 
(
     RowNum                INT NOT NULL IDENTITY (1,1) PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
   , RP_Name               VARCHAR(100) 
   , RPQualified_Name      VARCHAR(200) 
   , RP_Type               VARCHAR(100) 
   , RPCreatedDate         DATETIME      
   , RPLast_ModifiedDate   DATETIME     
   , RPActive              BIT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0 
)
GO
```

The declaration and use of a table variable works fine:

```
DECLARE @RPStats dbo.ttypRPStats
INSERT INTO @RPStats 
(
    RP_Name            
  , RPQualified_Name   
  , RP_Type            
  , RPCreatedDate      
  , RPLast_ModifiedDate
  , RPActive            
)
VALUES
(
     'Name'         -- RP_Name            
   , 'Longer.Name'  -- RPQualified_Name   
   , 'TheirType'    -- RP_Type            
   , '2004/07/04'   -- RPCreatedDate      
   , '2013/05/01'   -- RPLast_ModifiedDate
   , 1              -- RPActive            
)
select * from @RPStats
```

But what I'd like to be able to do is create a "real" table using the table type. I've read and re-read the CREATE TABLE command definition, and didn't detect a way to do this; and have conducted a great deal of research, but have not yet stumbled across a valid syntax. E.g. the following constructs do not work:

```
CREATE TABLE RPStats AS ttypRPStats
CREATE TABLE RPStats (ttypRPStats)
```

Is there a valid syntax to create a table using a table type?

I know I could send it all to a table variable first, then SELECT ... INTO the "real" table, 
but that would be the undesirable option of last resort.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: I am not aware of any way to do this directly, but given your "last resort" idea, have you considered doing: 1) Create Table Variable from the Type, 2) don't load any data yet, 3) SELECT * INTO RealTable FROM @TableVariable, 4) load data into RealTable ? I have not tried it but suspect that even an empty Table Variable would provide a result set structure that the SELECT...INTO construct would use to create an empty table of that structure. Would that be acceptable given that the data is only loaded once? If so, I can post this as an answer (assuming, of course, that it works ;-)

Comment: I tested and it copies the IDENTITY but not Default or Index / PK. So not ideal. I guess a proc can be created to read the structure of the Type and create a table from it. I will see if I can throw something together.

Comment: Actually, this is possible but not simple, so it will take me a day or two as I don't have the time right now to finish it.  If you need it quickly, you can run SQL Profiler and then in SSMS, script out the Table Type as CREATE to see what SQL it is running and then emulate that.

Comment: @srutzky--Great idea about creating the RealTable first, before dealing with any data. That gives me about 90% of what I was after...Thanks for your help.  Perhaps I can tap into the Type definition and create the table using dSQL.  I'll try that next.

Comment: no problem. Yes, I have already started writing the dynamic SQL to get the CREATE statement based on the Type definition, but that is the part that I was saying is a little tricky, especially if you want to support all various datatypes including User-Defined Types. Then you have Constraints (Check / Unique / PK / Default) and each one has its own definition ;-). If I get time later today I will try to finish it and post it as the answer.